# How to identify all minima in a non-PSD quadratic program (QP)?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, gams-math, quadratic-programming, non-convex

I have linearly constrained QP problems with multiple disjoint global optima (not PSD).  I'd like to make a QP solver characterize *all* of the globally optimal solutions.  Here is a very simple example of the sort of case that arises:

```
minimize f(x,y)=x*y
subject to:
[1] (x + y) <= 1
[2] (x + y) >= 0.5
[3] x >= 0
[4] y >= 0
```

Here, there is a continuous segment of optimal (f=0) solutions on the x-axis [0.5,1], and another disconnected segment of optimal solutions on the y-axis.  I've posed this problem to BARON with high values of NumLoc and NumSol, but it seems to give up prematurely after finding a single point solution.  (Tried BARON since it does seem adept at finding multiple point solutions in other problems.)

Are there better methods or solvers for such problems?

Comment: You can reformulate the KKT conditions as a linear MIP ([link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/06/solving-non-convex-qp-problems-as-mip.html)).  Then standard methods (solution pool, integer cuts) can be used to find alternate solutions.

Comment: The MIP translation suggested by Erwin Kalvelagen is looking promising; however it is a bit of work.  I had hoped one of the global solvers (tried BARON and ANTIGONE) would have a robust answer to this type of problem, i.e. a certificate that all branches were explored, but possibly this is too much to hope.